# 18.04 Bluetooth not working "BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found"

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom, xps

I use a Dell XPS 15 and Bluetooth works under Windows.

Under Ubuntu, it can't find any devices, and it cannot be found. I'm not even sure if the driver is configured properly...

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

As explained [here](https://itstillworks.com/convert-windows-drivers-linux-9821.html) and [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0Ist9aEKEg) I installed the Windows version supplied on the Dell website with `ndiswrapper`. The installation went well but unfortunately, I now get a message saying that bluez daemon is not running.

`lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` used to return this before the ndiswrapper installation:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:21d5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.028000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.061975] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.708451] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[   43.528813] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   43.528827] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   43.528829] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   43.528831] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   43.528835] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   43.634450] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[   43.662807] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[   43.664761] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[   43.680692] Bluetooth: hci0: XPS15
[   43.681689] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[   43.681706] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[   43.681708] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[   44.098227] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[   44.098673] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[   44.482264] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   44.482265] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   44.482268] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   61.264211] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   61.264216] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   61.264219] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 6819.806765] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[ 6820.314207] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[ 6820.315135] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[ 6821.040805] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[ 6821.041831] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[ 6821.057841] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
[ 6821.058831] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[ 6821.058841] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[ 6821.058842] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[10214.828239] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[10215.336003] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[10215.336936] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[10216.474374] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[10216.475366] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[10216.491453] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
[10216.492392] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[10216.492421] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[10216.492423] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[12401.663486] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[12402.171207] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[12402.172149] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[12402.909627] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[12402.910614] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[12402.926675] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
[12402.927647] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[12402.927675] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[12402.927676] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[13665.363988] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[13665.872066] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[13665.872992] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[13666.598910] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[13666.599918] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[13666.615904] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
[13666.616926] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[13666.616936] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[13666.616938] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[19586.950373] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[19587.462158] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[19587.463089] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[19588.596432] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[19588.597419] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[19588.613413] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
[19588.614406] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[19588.614417] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[19588.614418] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
[34544.717668] audit: type=1107 audit(1534369171.537:103): pid=1622 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=26655 label="snap.gitkraken.gitkraken" peer_pid=1621 peer_label="unconfined"
[34702.590382] audit: type=1107 audit(1534369329.409:106): pid=1622 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=27502 label="snap.gitkraken.gitkraken" peer_pid=1621 peer_label="unconfined"
[42411.520578] usb 1-1: device firmware changed
[42577.325134] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[42577.832502] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob failed with error -2
[42577.833443] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[42578.571135] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 102
[42578.572136] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2f
[42578.588139] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20703A1
[42578.589153] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.005) build 0000
[42578.589180] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2
[42578.589181] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd not found
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: It seems like my bluetooth device is Broadcom Corp BCM2045A0. However, Software & Updates / Additional Drivers doesn't find anything related to this and Dell's website only offers a .exe version of its driver. (I'm new to Linux so I might not be on the right track)

Comment: @Jeremy31 This post is interesting, but as they say, it is difficult to lay hand on a working version of the driver.

Comment: Try downloading https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM20703A1-0a5c-6410.hcd and rename the file to BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd and copy it to /lib/firmware/brcm   Then shutdown and boot